# Can someone tell me how to download wxPython Phoenix?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to download the contents of http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxPython/Phoenix/trunk but I don't want to single click the file, and that URL is not a valid git url.

Does anyone know how to download this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ProjectPhoenix - wxPyWiki Page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix):

> The current source code for Project Phoenix can be seen [here](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxPython/Phoenix/trunk), or you
>   can fetch the source directly from Subversion at [this link](https://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxPython/Phoenix/trunk/).

You can checkout the source code using following command. (You need to have a subversion installed)

```
svn checkout https://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxPython/Phoenix/trunk/ Phoenix
```

There's also read-only GitHub mirror: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I struggled so much to find the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to use Subversion. According to [their docs](http://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/code-repository/#setup), this command should work for anonymous checkout of wx *Widgets*:

```
svn checkout https://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk wxWidgets
```

Modifying that a bit, this should work for wx *Python* checkout:

```
svn checkout https://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxPython/Phoenix/trunk/ wxPython
```